# How would you punctuate someone referring to themselves by a nickname?

Tags: punctuation, commas, quotations, quotation-marks, nicknames

- Being the "family freeloader," as Tom liked to call himself, he felt as though he had no right to complain.

Should the comma come after the quotation marks, or is the current placement correct? Should there even be quotation marks at all?

Comment: I voted to reopen because "Should there even be quotation marks at all?" needs to be answered first.

Answer (score -1):

The American style would have the comma inside.

Comment: It's outside for the British style.